# First Search box is not working in spring

Tags: javascript, spring, postgresql

I am developing  a searchbox using spring mvc, javascript and postgresql as database.When I am giving any data in the first box (physician/clinic name), it is not taking any data.It is only taking the value of 2nd and 3rd search drop down i.e specialisation and city. So what must be the problem? Please help

Comment: Uh ok! what? Please show us some code which you have implemented, with any errors you might be getting

Comment: The first field is not taking any data ,whenever I am giving any name ,all the names that are present in the database are coming in the results.

Comment: Without looking at your code nobody will be able to help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.